# Does the sprite in LibGdx change if I change the origin?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision-detection

If I add a collision to a rotating sprite and I change the origin of the sprite so that it is rotating on a bigger radius does the origin effect the site of the collision? 
Oh, and is there a way how I can display the collision (as a border or smth)?

Comment: I think we are gonna need clarification on how you implemented collision

Comment: We need to know how the collisions are implemented... Did you use Box2D?